# How to trigger perforce changes before the submit using TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, perforce

I have currently CI system which triggers submit and particular stream and then builds the change and tests it.

However as I said it is done upon submit, meaning the change is merged before the testing.

So my question is how I can trigger the changes in an earlier stage? What is the best approach?

We are not using any IDEs for development.

Thanks!

Comment: Something along the lines of [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit)? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: The problem here that not all our developers use IDE for development

Comment: Then you should most likely add that info to the question since it's quite an important restriction, although if your workflow is quite custom maybe a mail to Teamcity support would be a better starting point.

Comment: Also upon every pre-commit we would like to test not only compilation but also run regression and a lot of other tests

Comment: Use a branch or a shelf, and test the branch or shelf, then merge into the mainline.

Answer (score 0):

To do it on the Perforce side, you'd use a `change-content` trigger, which runs prior to submit while the files are available in a staging area on the server (the in-flight change is treated as a shelf and can be accessed using the `@=change` syntax).  This allows a trigger script to access the content in-flight and reject it before it's finalized.

While a content trigger is running, the files are locked, and the submit will block the client session until it's finalized on the server and can report success, so you'd want to be careful about which codelines you enable something like this on.

Comment: If I understand correctly this trigger will start a build on every modified file and I'm looking for an option where developer will trigger the build when his changes are ready but before he submitted them

Comment: In that case what I'd go with would be a script that can run a build of a shelved changelist (which would be about the same as what you'd do in the trigger) and give the users a web UI to run it (maybe hook it into Swarm?)